# scroll to top in a webview when clicking status bar in IOS (not native implementation)

Tags: android, jquery, ios, scroll, webview

My app works with webViews and I'm trying to implement scroll to top when clicking the status bar in IOS.  I am using the cordova plugin statusTap to detect when the status bar is clicked and I managed to get scroll to top work without any native code.  the problem is that if I am clicking the status bar while in a scroll, the view kind of gets seizures and jumps around.

My code so far:

```
window.addEventListener('statusTap', onStatusTap);

function onStatusTap() {
    var appsContainer = $("#apps-container");
    appsContainer.animate({scrollTop: element.offset().top}, "slow");
}
```

I tried listening to scrolls and what not but I can't get away from the fact that during scrolls the value of

```
$("#apps-container").scrollTop
```

doesn't change so it's impossible to know if a scroll is taking place.

Does anybody have any idea for a non-native solution? Thanks in advance.